# Как загрузить приложение в iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Подскажите, как загрузить приложение в iTunes Connect. Заказчик мне дал доступ в роли менеджера приложения однако при добавлении приложения мне высвечивается надпись: "У вас нет готовых ID пакетов приложений для iOS". И ссылка "зарегистрировать id". При нажатии на эту ссылку я перехожу на страницу разработчика, где мне предлагают заплатить 99$ за регистрацию. Подскажите, без регистрации нельзя создать Id?

Comment: вы спросите у заказчика вашего, есть ли у него платный аккаунт. если нет, пусть сделает, а если есть, будем разбираться, что вы делаете не так

Comment: На сколько я знаю, без платного аккаунта не получить доступ к itunesconnect. Если аккаунт просрочен, то доступ остается, но приложение загрузить не получится - надо продлевать аккаунт.

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужно создать аккаунт инди разработчика или компании. Это стоит 100$ и 300$ в год соответственно. Потом создаешь appId, сертификаты и профижены. Без этого никак. Разве что попросить друга-разработчика чтоб он от себя выложил.

А у заказчика точно нет нужного аккаунта?