# Долларовый счет и iTunes Connect

Tags: ios

Всем привет!

Изучил тему выбора наиболее подходящей карты для вывода денег с App Store и мой выбор пал на "Альфа-банк". Открыл долларовый и рублевый счета. Для того, чтобы привязать долларовый счет к iTunes Connect, нужен SWIFT, но в самом начале при выборе банка, от меня требуют БИК. Этот БИК, естественно, у меня тоже есть и iTunes Connect его принимает, но в таком случае я не могу привязать свой долларовый счет. Скажите, как лучше всего поступить, чтобы привязать долларовый счет в iTunes Connect?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет ни малейшего отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563955/itunes-connect-имя-разработчика
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549217/Как-загрузить-приложение-в-itunes-connect
Ранее вопросы по iTunes Connect здесь задавались

Comment: если вас интересует мнение сообщества по поводу приемлемости вопросов, касающихся «привязки долларовых счетов», задайте об этом вопрос на [meta].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не одного ли рода этот вопрос с [другим по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383937/176217)?

Comment: @alexolut, нет. iTunes Connect имеет свою систему подачи реквизитов, а Google Play - свою.

Comment: @IuriiUshakov я не о различиях в подходах Apple/Google, а о тематике вопросов на StackOverflow. Вопрос по Android Александр поддержал, а этот хочет закрыть.